Integral using Fourier Transform
I have that $f(x) = xe^{-x}$ for $x\ge0$ else $f(x) = 0$.
Computing the FT is not a problem we arrive at $\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{1}{(1+i\xi)^2}$
Now I am asked to compute for each $\lambda>0$ the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{\lambda x}}{x(1+ix)^2}\,dx.$$.
It is simple to obtain that $$\frac{\hat{f}(\xi+\lambda)-\hat{f}(\xi - \lambda)}{2i} = \frac{\sin{\lambda \xi}}{(1+i\xi)^2}$$ I could almost use the inversion theorem but how do I get the $\xi$ term in the denominator? Any hints or notes on what I am doing wrong?

Let
$$
g(\lambda) = \int \frac{1}{x} \frac{\sin\lambda x}{(1+ix)^2} dx.
$$
Then
$g(0) = 0$
and
$$
g'(\lambda) = \int \frac{\cos\lambda x}{(1+ix)^2} dx.
$$
This last expression is close to be the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat f$ so you should readily get its value. From this and $g(0)=0$ you can then find $g(\lambda).$

How can I be sure that I am allowed to differentiate inside the integral? Dominated convergence theorem or?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Another way...
Notice that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{\lambda x}}{x(1+ix)^2}\,dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{\lambda x}}{x}\frac{1}{(1+ix)^2}\,dx
$$
is the inner product of a Fourier transform of some rectangular function and the Fourier transform of $f.$ Then use the Plancherel theorem to find the value.
